# JSOUP Authentication with ESPN

Tags: java, cookies, web-scraping, jsoup, espn

I had some code scraping ESPN fantasy league data with JSOUP that was working. Unfortunately with the new season the old season data was moved behind an authentication wall and I have been having some issues authenticating with ESPN. I have viewed the login headers/data with chrome dev tools, but am having trouble successfully authenticating. My goal is to get successful cookies from this request to pass on to all successive GET requests.

```
public static Connection.Response login(String username, String password) throws IOException{
    String url = "http://www.espn.com/fantasy/football/"; 
    Connection connection1 = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").method(Connection.Method.GET);
    Connection.Response response = connection1.execute();

    url = "https://ha.registerdisney.go.com/jgc/v5/client/ESPN-FANTASYLM-PROD/guest/login?langPref=en-US";
    Connection.Response connection2 = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36")
            .data("loginValue", username, "password", password)
            .header("host", "ha.registerdisney.go.com")
            .header("correlation-id", "dfc537c2-8fe0-40e2-8d72-04617d11a078")
            .header("authorization", "APIKEY 3gC3ZEgR+6YLQc8/oNygcm37bXong2jhstiAui9FOMN8hng3MWMQklxUrRG3rUMDLOS0+2wMeZ59gdT1xoL1u25NUg==")
            .header("content-type", "application/json")
            .header("conversation-id", "45dde0a2-3097-4821-910c-e074caac97b1")
            .header("Origin", "https://cdn.registerdisney.go.com")
            .header("expires", "-1")
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute();
```

I am using a get request on the url first and passing those cookies to seem like a human, and belive that I have all necessary values in the request, but just cannot get it working. Any reccommendations are appreciated!